# Get more than one $sums from single MongoDB aggregate based on $match creteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have mongodb document look like below:

```
{
  "_id": "4e6c6b35-6f6f-4cb6-86c3-0bd84af1f6e8",
  "employeeId": 1,
  "status": "Joined",
  "joiningDate": "2017-05-17T00:31:43.785+00:00"
}
```

and would like to get result like:

```
[{"employeeId: 1, "totalEmployees: 1, "joinedEmployees": 1}...]
```

I am trying to write spring mongo data aggregation function but not able to put match under group and how to use multiple groups?

```
Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(

     match(Criteria.where("employeeId").in(employeeIds)),
     group().sum("_id").as("totalEmployee"),

    //how to pipeline joined statues employees here and sum
     project("employeeId","totalEmployees", "joinedEmployees)
 );
```